# pythonでキー値とペアの製作、編集

Tags: python, array

```
lists = { ('田中', '山田 '): { '鈴木 ', '佐藤 ' },('伊藤', '鈴木 '): { '佐藤', '山田' },('佐藤', '田中 '): { '鈴木 ' }}
```

上記のようなリストを与えられたとき ('田中', '山田 '): { '鈴木 ', '佐藤 ' }のように():{}をひとまとまりにして{}ないを()の監督にしたいです。

```
lists = { ('田中', '山田 '): { '佐藤 ' },('伊藤', '鈴木 '): {'山田' },('佐藤', '田中 '): { '鈴木 ' }}
```

このように監督はいわゆるキーとして設定したいため、重複している要素を取り除きたいです。

importはなしでお願いします

手順：

```
#入力リスト
lists = { ('田中', '山田 '): { '鈴木 ', '佐藤 ' },('伊藤', '鈴木 '): { '佐藤', '山田' },('佐藤', '田中 '): { '鈴木 ' }}

#リスト内で重複していてペアがいるものを探してもしいたら消す。
#この場合リスト{'鈴木 '}を消してしまうとリストの数が減ってしますので{'鈴木 ', '佐藤 '}の'鈴木'をけす。
lists = { ('田中', '山田 '): { '佐藤 ' },('伊藤', '鈴木 '): { '佐藤', '山田' },('佐藤', '田中 '): { '鈴木 ' }}

#上記のことを繰り返す。
#この場合リスト('G')を消してしまうとリストの数が減ってしますので('G', 'J')の'G'をけす。
lists = { ('田中', '山田 '): { '佐藤 ' },('伊藤', '鈴木 '): {'山田' },('佐藤', '田中 '): { '鈴木 ' }}
```

上記の手順をいくつかの同じようなリストで試せるようにしたいです。
また、以下のような一意にできないリストの場合はNoneを返したいです。

```
liats = { ('田中', '鈴木 '): { '佐藤 ', '伊藤' },
('佐藤', '山田 '): { '伊藤', '田中' },
('伊藤', '田中'): { '佐藤 ' },
('山田 ', '田中'): set()}
```

長くなりましたがよろしくお願いします。‍♂️

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/nzo3o43l7fu7wu) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: 「○○を行いたい」的な要望はあるものの, そのために**何を行った**か, 行ったことについて**どこで躓いてる**か が記されていません。そのままだと『この質問は、調査や試行錯誤の跡がまったくない』に該当してしまうかも

Comment: 「上記のようなリストを与えられたとき」とありますが、質問文中の「リスト」とはどのような意味で使われていますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

```
# 複数の VALUE の要素に存在する VALUE の要素を抽出
def multi_vals(dic):
    vals = sum(map(list, dic.values()), [])
    return [v for v in set(vals) if vals.count(v) > 1]

# すべての VALUE の要素が１個で同じものがなければ true
def one_val_dic(dic):
    lst = [*dic.values()]
    return all(len(v) == 1 == lst.count(v) for v in dic.values())

# VALUE の要素数を１にする（VALUE 内要素が他の VALUE 内にあれば、この重複を削除する）
def to_oneval_dic(dic):
    def reduce_dic(dic_, v):
        dic = dic_.copy()
        for k in dic.keys():
            if len(dic[k]) > 1 and v[0] in dic[k]:
                dic[k] = dic[k]-{v[0]}
                if (vals:=multi_vals(dic)):
                    dic = reduce_dic(dic, vals)
                if dic and one_val_dic(dic):
                    return dic
                dic = dic_.copy()
        return None
    return dic if one_val_dic(dic) else reduce_dic(dic, multi_vals(dic))

dic = {('田中','山田'):{'鈴木','佐藤'},('伊藤','鈴木'):{'佐藤','山田'},('佐藤','田中'):{'鈴木'}}
dic2 = to_oneval_dic(dic)
print(dic2)  # {('田中','山田'):{'佐藤'},('伊藤','鈴木'):{'山田'},('佐藤','田中'):{'鈴木'}}
```